# Bootstrap Tabs Not Active nor Showing Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a personal website and I am running into a bootstrap err. It seems pretty common and I cant seem to fix it with anything I have read up on. I have the following code and any help is, well... helpful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  activaTab('about');
});

function activaTab(tab) {
  "use strict";
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#school">School</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nifty">Other Nifty Items</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div id="about" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      le content
    </div>
    <div id="work" class="tab-pane fade">
      le content
    </div>
    <div id="school" class="tab-pane fade">
      le content
    </div>
    <div id="nifty" class="tab-pane fade">
      le content
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What kind of error? What do you expect? What it shows instead?

Comment: It works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hh8Ldf0y/)

Comment: Your code seems to work fine did you make sure to load jquery.js file before bootstraps.js file?

Comment: @HectorOrdonez yeah, everyone seems to say that it responds fine, but when i export out to google chrome from dreamweaver the content doesnt switch. I might just have a screwy div class somewhere... I will check it out in a bit.